# Changing jquery-mockjax return data in the middle of a mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, mockjax

I'm writing tests with mocha that check that a changing state polled from a rest api is rendered correctly. Is it possible to change what the mocked endpoint returns in the middle of the test? I've tried overriding the mocked endpoint and using `var` as the data and changing it but neither works.

With override:

```
it("should render correctly") {
  loadPage(done, {init: function() {
    testUtils.mockjax("/url", {"data": "data"})
  }, onload: function() {
    expect($$("#data")).to.be.visible()
    testUtils.mockjax("/url", {"data": ""})
    clock.tick(5000)
    expect($$("#data")).not.to.be.visible() # does not work
    ...
    done()
  }
}
```

With variable:

```
it("should render correctly") {
  var data = {"data": "data"}
  loadPage(done, {init: function() {
    testUtils.mockjax("/url", data)
  }, onload: function() {
    expect($$("#data")).to.be.visible()
    data =  {"data": ""}
    clock.tick(5000)
    expect($$("#data")).not.to.be.visible() # does not work
    ...
    done()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by setting up a [custom handler function](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax#dynamically-generating-mock-definitions) versus the basic url and data matching. You would need to set up this mock *before* your test block, but then you could inspect the incoming request data and determine whether to match and what to return:

```
$.mockjax(function(requestSettings) {
  if ( requestSettings.url === '...' ) {
    return {
      responseText: "foo"  // you can change this based on the incoming request
    };
  }
  // If you get here, there was no match
  return;
});
```